# How to make a jar file from code?

Tags: java, android, jar

I have some java code written in a text file, now I want to create a jar file to use that file as a library in my android project. So what would be the best way to make a jar file from this point. Please note that I have some code written in a textfile and saved as a .txt. If I rename that file to .java and use this code

```
jar cf filename.jar file(s)
```

a jar file is created but when I decompile it in java decompiler it doesnt show the packages and that codes that's why I am unable to use it's methods. What would be the best way to do this? I need help

Comment: I'm curious, why are you doing this?

Comment: Because I need to provide this to my client as a jar file, and I am also curious to know something new :)

Comment: Typically you have to compile your Java code to .class files and then you can combine your class files together into a jar file.  However, with Android I'm not exactly sure if you can do that because Android doesn't use a standard JVM, it uses it's own (Dalvik).

Comment: How can I do this? can you refer me some example?

Comment: @Reyjohn I think what HeatfanJohn is saying, is to do a java myclass.java, and then the other thing you are doing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the classes in your library they must be compiled and you have to manually create all the packages subfolders.

So :
1. Make a folder
2. Create each package subfolderds in it (com/foo/bar/xxx)
3. Compile each of your .java files and put them it the correct subfolders
4. Zip your folder and rename it with a .jar extension

But it is hard to do this by code, why don't create it with your IDE ?

Comment: Your answer is making sense, can you please say how to compile java files?

Comment: If you are using eclipse : Right click on your project > Export > Java > JAR File. Then select the packages and source files you want to be included. Check the option "Export generated class files and resources", if you want to export the source files too (not needed for execution) check the option "Export Java source files and reousrces". Select a destination JAR and click on "Finish".

Answer (score 1):

Creating a jar File in Windows Command Prompt

Start Command Prompt.
Navigate to the folder that holds your class files:

```
cd \mywork

Rem -- Set path to include JDK’s bin.  For example:
path c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.5.0_09\bin;%path%

Rem -- Compile your class(es):
javac *.java

Rem -- Create a manifest file:
echo Main-Class: DanceStudio >manifest.txt

Rem -- Create a jar file:
jar cvfm DanceStudio.jar manifest.txt *.class

Rem -- Test your jar file by trying to execute it
Rem -- This will not apply for a library JAR file without any main
java -jar DanceStudio.jar
```

Comment: plz re arrange your answer, its looking clumsy :(